# Excel: Matrix Inversion

Tags: matrices

I have the following matrix:

$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
26 & 209.95 & 1699.0025 & 13778.493625 & 111977.48388125 & 911948.597109063\\
209.95 & 1699.0025 &13778.493625 & 111977.48388125 & -911948.597109063 & 7442315.21214533\\
1699.0025 & 13778.493625 & 111977.48388125 & -911948.597109063 & 7442315.21214533 & 60859617.3169286\\
13778.493625 & 111977.48388125 & -911948.597109063 & 7442315.21214533 & -60859617.3169286 & 498674841.078199\\
111977.48388125 & -911948.597109063 & 7442315.21214533 & -60859617.3169286 & 498674841.078199 & 4094065648.25843\\
911948.597109063 & -7442315.21214533 & 60859617.3169286 & -498674841.078199 & 4094065648.25843 & 33676104461.2376\end{array} \right) 
$$

I used Excel to find the inverse of this matrix:

[image]

As confirmed on Mathematica, the inverse is incorrect. Any possible explanation as to why?

Comment: Looks like really bad conditioning of the matrices to me and apparently Excel cannot deal with the numerical problems associated with that..

Comment: Never mind that, why on earth are you using excell to do linear algebra?

Comment: @air What do you mean by bad conditioning of the matrices? What can I do about that?

Comment: @5xum I have a lot of data on Excel...What else can I use for an accurate inversion of the matrix?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number

Comment: @air Any suggestions for what else I can use?

Comment: Since it's a very small matrix you can probably use a symbolic (here: arbitrary precision) inverse matrix calculator. I guess that mathematica should do the trick, although I have never used it.

Comment: @air Is the matrix ill-conditioned (which, from my understanding, means sensitive to small changes) because of the large range of values within it? [As the top left-most value is 26, whereas the bottom-right most value has an order of magnitude equal to ten] - If not, is there a straight-forward reason as to why it is?

Comment: @Moo Thanks for the link - it did clear some questions I had in mind, however, I still do not know (after reading the PDF and doing some of my own research online) whether the matrix is ill conditioned because of the large range of values within it [As the top left-most value is 26, whereas the bottom-right most value has an order of magnitude equal to ten]...Do you know if this is the reason? If not, do you know what else could have caused it to be?

Comment: You said that "Any number of things could cause that - including small and large numbers" - is this a fact, or are you assuming? I'm sorry, I don't mean to be condescending, I just want to be mathematically correct (as I am writing a report to do with this...)